# How to design a plane to be in the center of the viewport at any window size

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to draw a plane (with GL_QUADS) in OpenGL (c++, OS: windows) so that it is aligned to the center of the screen.

What I mean is that the origin will be in the center of the plane at any window resize.

I know I have to use the viewport coordinates and sizes, but I cannot configure how to use them.

Also, I am using `gluPerspective`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin has nothing to do with your window size. When you resize the window, recalculate the aspect ratio of the window (window.width / window.height) and reset your projection matrix with another call to gluPerspective using the new aspect.

After this, as long as you glLoadIdentity() into the modelview matrix you should be able to draw a quad at the center of the screen using

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-.5f,.5f,-1);
glVertex3f(-.5f,-.5f,-1);
glVertex3f(.5f,-.5f,-1);
glVertex3f(.5f,.5f,-1);
glEnd();
```

That should place a unit sized quad at the center of the screen.

Comment: I am doing what you've said in your 1st paragraph already. 

When should I do the glLoadIdentity() call? 
I need this to create a pause menu for my game, so I would need to restore the previous state after a keypress. How could I do that? By using push and pop matrix?

Comment: Yes, you would push/pop the modelview, just as 'All the Rage' posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-.5f,.5f,-1);
glVertex3f(-.5f,-.5f,-1);
glVertex3f(.5f,-.5f,-1);
glVertex3f(.5f,.5f,-1);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

Note that this still uses all of your 3D rendering state, such as depth test, shading, etc.. Most likely you'll want to turn that off.